# Spring Data: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(roles)]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring, and I was following this tutorial [Spring Rest Services](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/)

to understand how oAuth works with REST APIs.

Prior to this, my app was running smoothly.

While working with the tutorial, it required me to have my `User` entity implement `UserDetails`. And I had to add an extra `List<String> roles` because it is used in my `UserDetailsImpl` service which implements `UserDetailsService`.

And now when I run `mvn spring-boot:run` I get the error that's mentioned in the title.

I looked up online, but most of the issues were related to table associations via a particular column, but in my code, there is no type of association mapped to/from `roles` column.

Here is my `User` entity:

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private List<String> roles;

    public User (){

    }

    public User (String email, String name, String password, UUID id, List<String> roles){
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.id = id;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

And this my `UserDetailsImp` service:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsImp implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.getOneByEmail(email);
        UserBuilder builder = null;

        if( user != null){
            builder.username(user.getEmail()).password(user.getPassword()).roles(String.join("",user.getRoles()));
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field `private List<String> roles` has unknown type in the DB.
Try using `@ElementCollection` annotation.
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html

Comment: Oh, thank you. I had `text[]` as the column type in my Postgres DB, and had `List` for the same column in Hibernate